# Google console warning: your app took over 20s app to start up

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Recently I published new update and I received this warning. It happened on Pixel 2 with Android P on board. I tried another app and very similar problem. I am not sure if it is problem with Google pre-tests or my code (tested on several apps, some got this warning, some not). I think it is not connected with long proceed in onCreate method. Inside I only put layout, thats all. On button click I start all application logic.

**EDIT**

In my layout there is only toolbar and couple of Text Views, so posting only onCreate
MainActivity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setToolbar()
        advertViewer = AdvertViewer(addAdvertToContainer(), this)
        mainViewHolder = MainViewHolder(this, advertViewer)
        mainViewHolder.setUpFloatingButton(this)
        mainViewHolder.setDefaultValues(this)
        presenter.onCreate(this)
        Promote.initRateThisApp(this)
    }
```

MainPresenter.kt

```
override fun onCreate(context: Activity) {
        initGoogleApiClient(context)
        locationCoordinator = LocationCoordinator(context, viewer, googleApiClient, mainModel, timer, onlineCoordinator)
        timer.start()
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Timer

```
private val handler = Handler()
    private var runnable: Runnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            locationBuffer++
            if(stopCounter == 0)
                stopListenerCallback()
            stopCounter--
            if(isNewData){
                updateCallback()
                locationBuffer = 0
            }
            oneSecondCallback()
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
        }
    }
```

Comment: show your main layout and mains code that is loaded

Comment: I see this randomly on the Pixel 2 P device in the Play Store testing too. I see no such issue on an emulated Pixel 2 P, nor does there appear to be an issue (> 20 s load time) when reviewing the video of the test on the Play Store. I suspect it's just a bug in the Play Store testing/reporting.

Comment: What does `timer` do?